# SQL Error (1114): The table 'global_priv' is full

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, xampp

I can no longer add users to my database. I only get the error:

```
SQL Error (1114): The table 'global_priv' is full
```

I researched this issue, and the my.ini config for innodb_data_file_path did not have a cap. But I also tried setting it to 2GBs, but still to no avail:

```
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend:max:2048M
```

I also have plenty of space on the drive mysql is installed on. Aside from that, my `global_priv` table has a total of 7 rows.

Specifically, I'm using XAMPP 7.4.27 on Windows 10 x64, with MariaDB 10.4.22.

Comment: "max" is a relic of the old days, when disks were only a few GB.  Get rid of that part of the  config.  Meanwhile, how big is the file `ibdata1`?  How much free disk do you have?  How big is global_priv (probably in the subdirectory "mysql").

Comment: Thanks for the input, Rick James. ibdata1 is 77MBs, global_priv.frm is only 2KBs, and they're on a drive with 93GBs available, which is why I suspect something else is wrong..

Comment: Did you restart after changing the `max:`?

Comment: Yes, I restarted after every change.

Comment: [out of ram](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198569/the-table-is-full-mariadb)? I can't see anything in the bug report. Try to upgrade to [10.4 latest](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/release-notes-mariadb-104-series/) and otherwise [report a bug](https://jira.mariadb.org)

Comment: Nothing / no one helped. Got sick of it enough that I updated my entire MariaDB install completely. Exported all my dbs first, and started a completely new db system. Seems to work now. Hopefully never happens again. Just a waste of time reimporting all my dbs / users.